# Writing a Code Poem

Tags: python

I have this piece of Python code I'm writing for a "Code Poetry" contest it should be error free, but I'm not sure what's wrong with it.  I appreciate any input.

```
# Creation
def dustBit(mass, rotation, velocity):
    bitMass = mass
    bitRotation = rotation
    bitVelocity = velocity

def dustCloud(mass, rotation):
    mass = mass
    rotation = rotation

def Stir(dustBit1, dustBit2):
    cloudMass = dustBit1.mass + dustBit2.mass
    cloudRotation = dustBit1.velocity * dustBit2.velocity
    return  dustCloud(cloudMass, cloudRotation)

def Spark(dustCloud): return StellarObject(dustCloud.mass)

def Life (planet, seed): return None

dustBit1 = dustBit(8.3, 5.2, -7.1)
dustBit2 = dustBit(5.3, 3.2, 5.4)

Cloud = Stir(dustBit1, dustBit2)
Planets = []
for i in range(8):
    Planets[i] = Stir(Cloud, dustBit1)

Sol = Spark(Cloud)

Life(Planets[2])
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: As a start, you're calling `Life` with one parameter but it expects two (`planet` and `seed`). But what do you mean with "I'm not sure what's wrong with it"?

Comment: What are you expecting us to do......

Comment: I'm voting to close this. It is not (yet) a real question.

Comment: Your function defined for `dustCloud` isn't going to magically have a attribute `mass`

Answer (score 1):

You define functions, not classes here, and all of them will return `None` in the end.

Comment: This poem shows that life means nothing.